# Display editText and a Button in Another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I am using `Linear Layout(Horizontal)` for my `Android` application. I am using two buttons for my screen which I have called as `Chat` and `Draw`. I want to display a second activity on clicking on `Chat` button in which I have an area for `editText` and a corresponding button called as `Enter` for entering the text.

In the `DisplayMessageActivity` class which I am using for `Chat` button, I have created the layout for `editText` and `Enter` button too. But however, on clicking on `Chat` I am not being able to see the area for `editText` and the button `Enter`.

Code in `MainActivity.java` :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.appfirst.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void chatMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent_chat = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent_chat);
}

public void drawing(View view) {
    Intent intent_draw = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent_draw);
}

}
```

code in `DisplayMessageActivity.java` :

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

What code should I write in the `OnCreate` function of `DisplayMessageActivity` class so that I am able to get the desired view ?

Can someone help me with the code. I am totally new to Android Development Framework. Thanks and Regards.

Comment: did you create XML file for edit text and button

Comment: You are missing setContentView(R.layout.display_message); in DisplayMessageActivity's onCreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post i understand that u have 2 layouts 1 with 2 buttons `"Chat"` and `"Draw"`.And when clicking chat u have to call another activity with `Edittext` and `Enter` button in it.If this is the case you simply call the `Intent`.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,yourclass.class);
startactivity(intent);
```

In Oncreate of your `DisplayMessage` do the following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
     setContentView(R.layout.YourXml.Xml);       

}
```

Comment: yes exactly.. thanks. What should I write in the function `OnCreate` in `DisplayMessage` class ?? Should I leave it blank ??

Comment: Without code how can i able to say..Please post some of your code..K anyway  ..You can  write your logic what is needed for that screen(DisplayMessage )..IF you post your code i can explain you clearly what you needed..

Comment: kk .. check my edited question. I have posted some code there.

Comment: Thats my glad that i helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

    setContentView(R.layout.activityxml);    

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

For more information look the below example [link](http://seasonofrejoice.blogspot.in/)

Answer (score 1):

In your second activity you need to put the following line `setContentView(R.layout.whatEverYourLayoutIsCalled);`, put it right after `super.onCreate(...);`